# error: couldn't open .png

Tags: python, pygame

Can someone help me identify where I went wrong? Thanks. I get: `pygame.error: Couldn't open space.png`.  My code is as follows:

```
import random, math, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("orbit demo") 

space = pygame.image.load("space.png").convert()


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_ESCAPE]:
        sys.exit()

    #draw backgroud
    screen.blit(space, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: where is space.png located from the scripts perspective?

Comment: 2 probable reasons:
1. The filename is not present in the current directory. Solution: Point it to the correct path
2. Insufficient Read permissions on the directory where space.png is present or on the space.png file itself. Solution: Change the permissions and run again

Answer (score 1):

You may have to do the following:

```
import pygame
import os

try:
    # load from subfolder 'data' 
    background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("data","background640x480_a.jpg"))
    ball = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("data","snake.gif"))
except:
    raise UserWarning, "Unable to find the images in the folder 'data' :-( "
```

This was obtained from the Python Game Book website. Basically you tell it where to look (in the code above, it is the data folder. If it cannot find it, it reports the User Warning.

So in the example that I'm writing for my game, I have an images folder, so I do this

```
self.image = background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images","starship.png")).convert()
```

I am a newbie to this, but reading suggests this is how you do it.

EDIT - The other reason could be. Is it the correct format (e.g. png) or have you named the file something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the full path of the image(s), example: C:/Python34/your_folder/file_name.png

Note: in your python code to refer to a path you can't use "\", must use "/"
the "\" has a specific meaning in python.

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was I was not running the command from within the folder containing the game file. Both my `.py` file and `.png` file are in the top level, so I `cd` into that and ran and it worked.